# Find optimal hyperparameters of both Models and Vectorizers using GridSearchCV

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, gridsearchcv

I wrote this method that returns all scores for each combination of Models and Vectorizers passed to it using GridSearchCV in order to find the optimal parameters

```py
def text_classification(dataframe, vectorizer, model, parameters):
    """
    Perform free text binary classification using a given dataframe, vectorizer, and model.
    Returns an array of scores for each fold of 5-fold cross-validation.
    """
    X = vectorizer.fit_transform(dataframe['message'])
    y = dataframe['message_type']

    gs = GridSearchCV(model, parameters, cv=5)
    scores = cross_val_score(gs, X, y, cv=5)

    return scores
```

Then I loop through two arrays of Vectorizers and Models:

```py
# Define vectorizers and models
vectorizers = [TfidfVectorizer(), CountVectorizer()]
models = [LogisticRegression(), RandomForestClassifier(), MultinomialNB(), ComplementNB(), BernoulliNB()]

# Define hyperparameters for each model
parameters = {
    LogisticRegression: {'C': [1, 10, 100, 1000]},
    RandomForestClassifier: {'n_estimators': [10, 100, 1000]},
    MultinomialNB: {'alpha': [0.1, 0.5, 1.0]},
    ComplementNB: {'alpha': [0.1, 0.5, 1.0]},
    BernoulliNB: {'alpha': [0.1, 0.5, 1.0]},
}


for vectorizer in vectorizers:
    for model in models:
        # Perform cross-validation and evaluate model as well as optimal parameters
        scores = text_classification(df, vectorizer, model, parameters[model.__class__])
        print(f"Vectorizer: {vectorizer.__class__.__name__}, Model: {model.__class__.__name__}, Scores: {scores}")
```

The above works, but it does not find the optimal parameters for the Vectorizer as well.

I adapted my method in order to use GridSearchCV in both vectorizer/model to find the optimal params, and pass two separate param dicts for models/vectorizers:

```py
    gs_model = GridSearchCV(model, model_parameters, cv=5)
    gs_vectorizer = GridSearchCV(vectorizer, vectorizer_parameters, cv=5)
    gs = make_pipeline(gs_vectorizer, gs_model)
    scores = cross_val_score(gs, X, y, cv=5)
```

But when I loop `text_classification` passing the two new param objects/dicts:

```py
        scores = text_classification(df, vectorizer, model, model_parameters=[model.__class__], vectorizer_parameters=[vectorizer.__class__])
```

I get the following error:

```
in check_scoring
    raise TypeError(
TypeError: If no scoring is specified, the estimator passed should have a 'score' method. The estimator TfidfVectorizer() does not.
```

Comment: As the error said, `TfIdfVectorizer` does not have the score attribute, meanwhile the `GridSearchCV` requires the `score` either it was user-defined ot the `score` attribute inside the first param itself. I think getting to know the further stack trace will also help

Comment: @DhanaD. I assume then I can't use GridSearchCV with Vectorizers?... (I added some more meat to the question)

Comment: Yes, you cannot use it directly. However, I think it may be possible if you create model and vectorizer inside a function and make it having the `score` attribute. You can also refer to https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html (I guess you use sklearn's)

Comment: I appreciate the comment. I read somewhere that it actually doesn't make sense to pass the Vectorizer in GridSearch so before I go on to implement a workaround I'd like to understand more if what I am doing makes sense ...